# Viewport android not working under android 4.2.2

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an android project , with webviews , the problem is the website is working with viewport  :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
```

so my webview is created just like that:

```
    WebView web = new WebView(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    web.loadUrl(liens.get(index).getUrl());
```

this is working on phones with android higher than 4.4.x , but when i use it on a samsung galaxy s4 with android 4.2.2 , nothing is changed , the webview doesn't take the viewport on consideration , but when i open the same url on google chrome for example , its working very well , means that the google chrome is taking the viewport on consideration.

what can i do to fix this probleme . please
note that i can't make changes on the web site.

Comment: If I remember correctly, WebView was Webkit based up to Android 4.2 and is Chrome based since 4.4 - so maybe look for a Webkit specific issue/workaround.

Comment: Hi Nedal, did you find any workaround to tackle this problem?

Comment: @TorstenRömer Can you please help with that?

Comment: @RSB Sorry, I'm unable to help, I think it simply doesn't work as expected in Webkit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338337/709426

Comment: @RSB I think `webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` helps at least to fit the page on the screen instead of zoomed in.